# Pass by reference deprecated notice for array_unshift calls - doesn't work without pbr

Tags: php

I have PHP 5.3.8 and the error I get is on this line:

```
array_unshift($this->parents, &$this->parent);
```

The value of $this->parent comes from:

```
$this->parent[$key] = array();
$this->parent = &$this->parent[$key];
```

The error message is:

> Deprecated: Call-time pass-by-reference has been deprecated in /var/www/vhosts/mauilistings.net/httpdocs/xml/kd_xmlrpc.php on line 136

Taking off the & sign does not help, the function no longer works.

Comment: whats the value of $this->parent ?

Comment: just remove & it will work

Comment: Well `array_unshift` should still work, however you might need to change some other function as well.

Comment: why are you prefixing $this->parent[$key] with & ?

Comment: $this->parent[$key] is an array

Answer (score 2):

From [PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php#language.references.pass):

> As of PHP 5.3.0, you will get a warning saying that "call-time pass-by-reference" is deprecated when you use `&` in `foo(&$a);`. And as of PHP 5.4.0, call-time pass-by-reference was removed, so using it will raise a fatal error.

Comment: Actually it is working with the &, I'm just wondering how I can keep it working and get rid of the deprecated message.

Comment: @LawrenceDeSouza use `error_reporting(0)` when you host your site on server. At development side don't use `error_reporting(0)`.

Comment: ok I commented off error_reporting(E_ALL), but i kept  ini_set("display_errors", 1)  , it still gives the deprecated notice